# Renumbering ethernet devices in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ethernet

I have a VMware machine running Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic) with three virtual ethernet NICs. For some reason, the kernel has decided that these NICs are: `eth3`, `eth4`, and `eth5`. There is no `eth0`-`eth2`. How can I force the kernel to renumber these three ethernet devices to be `eth0`, `eth1` and `eth2`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As root, edit the `NAME=` fields in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, save, and reboot.